# MDX - Get total from selected period

Tags: ssas, mdx

I want to calculate a percentage value of a selected period. I don't know how to handle it.

```
              | Quantity | CalcMember |

January       |     5    |            |

   2015-01-01 |     1    |    20%     |

   2015-01-02 |     2    |    40%     |

   2015-01-03 |     2    |    40%     |
```

I need only the total of my selected period from day X to X and not the result of the whole month for my calculation.

The issue is summarizing the filtered members within the calculated member.

edit: I found a solution!

I have to create a dynamic set

```
CREATE DYNAMIC SET CurrentCube.[SelectedDates] AS [Date].[YearMonth].[Date].Members;

CREATE MEMBER CURRENTCUBE.[Measures].[Percentage] AS 
[Measures].[Qty] / SUM([SelectedDates], [Measures].[Qty]),
format_string = "Percent"
```

but this works only when the dates are in the rows...

Comment: So is there still a question here?

Comment: yes, it is not the solution of my problem..

Comment: Can you edit your question and simplify it, then?  I'm not sure what you're asking, since you solved it, but only when the dates are in the rows, whatever that means.

Comment: Percent of total calcs are hard because it is hard for the cube developer to anticipate what the report author intends. Do you only need this ability in Excel pivots? If so there is a built in Show Values As... % of Total feature in Excel. If that's acceptable and you can't find that feature let me know and I can describe further.

Comment: Can you show an example table where your calc doesn't work as intended? And describe what result would be correct.

Comment: @GregGalloway yes! exactly like the "Show Values As" function only dynamically as measure value and also take into account my selection, is it possible to handle this as measure ?

Comment: Show Values As - % of Parent Row Total

Comment: @Blin4ik yep. That is what I would recommend. Will that work?

Answer (score 0):

Use EXISTING function

```
CREATE HIDDEN DYNAMIC SET [SelectedDates] AS
  EXISTING [Date].[YearMonth].[----smallest level of your hierarchy---].Members;

CREATE MEMBER CURRENTCUBE.[Measures].[Percentage] AS 
  [Measures].[Qty] /    // or somethinng like [Original Value] from numeric calculations if you want to do that for multiple measures at once
        Sum 
            ([SelectedDates], [Measures].[Qty]
        );
```